# Eclipse not detecting the installed java

Tags: java, eclipse

I had installed Eclipse Galileo first and after that installed Java.

But it is not detecting my java.

What configuration changes can I make so that Eclipse can run my java programs?

========================== Edited ================================

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the exact jvm you want to use through:

- a `-vm` argument
- directly within the **[`eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)**

Once started, you can reference as many JVM you need in the `Installed JRE` preference panel

[alt text http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/3307/eclipseinstalledjre2.png](http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/3307/eclipseinstalledjre2.png)

Finally, you need to reference the JVM you need in the `Libraries` tab, in your `Java Build Path` properties of your Java project (as mentioned by [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279452/steve) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325935/eclipse-not-detecting-the-installed-java/2326116#2326116)):

[alt text http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/5947/eclipseinstalledjre3.png](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/5947/eclipseinstalledjre3.png)

Comment: I followed your answer but the problem is still a problem. So I have attached a screenshot showing redline under import statements.

Comment: Now the problem is solved. I forgot to add the jre-library to the project buildpath.

Comment: @Yatendra: good point. I have updated the answer to illustrate that last setting.

Answer (score 4):

It seems, that your project doesn't have the JVM in it's Build Path.

Right-Click on your project. Choose Build Path --> Add Libraries.... Take JRE System Library and choose a JVM for your project.